# JavaFx Project Working in Netbeans and not working when we use CMD java command

Tags: javafx, netbeans, runtime

I have developed a small JavaFX application which will call the other Java based application using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); in a separate thread.

I have tested my application using Netbeans it is working properly.

When I try to execute the same in command line using the below statement:
java - jar Myprogram.jar. I am able to launch the application but the call of Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd) code is not executed.

Please suggest if I am missing something when trying to execute using cmd line

Thanks
Srikanth

Comment: Are you on Windows? What is the value of 'cmd' you are passing in?

Comment: Please check what the current working path is, maybe its not as expected.

Comment: Hi Alexiy, I am on Windows. The values I am passing for cmd are as shown:     java -cp <classpath> -javaagent:./lib/MyAgent.jar=arg1